# Windows security pop up never goes away

Tags: outlook

I'm running into a head scratcher type of situation. I have a user who has reported that they are getting a Windows Security pop up from outlook that keeps showing up even after clicking Cancel or signing out/in to Outlook.

[image]

Luckily, the user didn't put in their credentials.

Below are some things I've checked from a security standpoint:

1. Checked the URL in the image using an analysis tool. Nothing malicious came back.
2. Checked the URL "http://cdn.goalline.ca" it redirects to  "https://stacksports.goalline.ca/". Nothing malicious there as well.
3. Checked the domain cdn.goalline.ca and nothing malicious. Appears to be registered 20yrs ago and lines up with the stacksports site stating that it was founded in 2002.
4. Checked enterprise AV, MS Defender and nothing malicious comes back.

Can anyone help in why this keeps popping up for the user? Also, how do we stop this from re-occurring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just an ical feed; the user must have subscribed to this calendar, or possibly via RSS subscription in their Outlook client.

It's probably popping up because you have some sort of outbound web proxy or filter that depends on user authentication would be my wild guess, because that URL is not requiring authentication if I hit it. You'd need to check the logs on your border device(s) or run Wireshark on the user's PC to get a clearer picture though.

To remove it, you could either find and fix the auth issue, or simply unsubscribe them from the resource. Depending on your version of Outlook, this will be under Accounts and look something like this (mine is empty). It'll either be here in Calendars, or under RSS Feeds.
[image: Dialog box for Outlook Internet Calendars]

Here's the URL from your screenshot:
http://cdn.goalline.ca/subscribe_ical.php?cal=6eee1-201407-201408-31153-1721

Comment: It could just be a RSS feed and NOT a calendar (even though it says ical in the URL). Many companies have both ans serve them from the same server-logic, which can be confusing.

Comment: @Tonny we checked the RSS feeds and nothing there. However, we did find a ```subscribe_ical``` entry under Internet Calendar and just removed it. I'll note this in the future to check both tabs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10 and 11 this solved the headache for me:

Look at windows registry if you have these Keys:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL set to zero.
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\DisableADALatopWAMOverride set to 1.

If you have, backup and delete them

Then:
-> Windows Key + I
-> Accounts
-> Access work or school

Here you will find the Exchange 365 accounts -> disconnect them

Now, the standard Exchange 365 credentials window appears.

Note: In my case, desesperated, before this, I deleted de Outlook profile, I don't know if it's mandatory to do
Note 2: Sorry for my english

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it did the trick !
I've spent hours finding solutions for this pop up appearing suddenly without any reason.